# Complexity of checking if a set is an additive basis

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, additive-combinatorics

A set of nonnegative integers $A$ is said to be an additive basis of order $k$ if every nonnegative integer is equal to the sum of $k$ elements of $A$. For example, [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) says that the squares are an additive basis of order $4$

Suppose that we want to check, experimentally, if $A$ is an additive basis of order $k$. Of course, we cannot test every nonnegative integer, so we have to consider an upper limit $N$ and check if every integer in $[0, N]$ is the sum of $k$ elements of $A$. How efficiently can we do that?

Formally, what can we say about the complexity of an algorithm that takes as input a positive integer $k$, a nonnegative integer $N$, and a set $A_N \subseteq [0, N]$ (such that $A_N = A \cap [1, N]$, for some fixed $A$); and returns as output **True** if every integer in $[0,N]$ is the sum of $k$ elements of $A$, and **False** otherwise?

Note that such complexity necessarily depends on $A$, and so the answer may be more or less complex, depending on how much one digs into the structure of $A$. The obvious algorithm that computes all the sums of $k$ elements of $A_N$ has complexity $O(|A_N|^k / k!)$ (Assuming that summing two integers has costs $O(1)$). Can we do better in terms of the cardinality $|A_N|$ only?

Comment: For large $A$ you can probably do better by calculating the Fourier transform of $A$ and then writing the convolution as an average of $k$th powers of the FT. I think this gives $O(N^2\log N)$ running time, which is better for large $A$.

Comment: @ThomasBloom Though FFT-based algorithm is clearly a good idea, I think you might be underestimating its running time. As $k$ increases, you will need to do calculations to ever higher precision. I expect the required precision (and hence the running time) to grow linearly with $k$.

Comment: @BorisBukh Maybe Fourier transform over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, with $p > kN$ a prime, can avoid precision problems.